# What does the statement painted on this P-51 mean?

Tags: fuel

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwFdTbmECDo), there is a shot of the side of a P-51 Mustang.

[image]

The side of the plane is painted with:

> SERVICE THIS AIRPLANE WITH GRADE 100/150 FUEL. IF NOT AVAILABLE T.O. 06-5-1 WILL BE CONSULTED FOR EMERGENCY ACTION
>   SUITABLE FOR AROMATIC FUEL

What does this mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are instructions for a compatible fuel substitute for 100/150 octane fuel per Technical Order 06-5-1 if AvGas is unavailable to the service crews in an emergency.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's a reminder that 1) fuel should be 100-150 octane, and 2) when not available, a gasoline rich in aromatic hydrocarbons (i.e. high-octane) could be used in emergencies, following the document T.O. 06-5-1.